# Update multivalued field, not getting multiple values in SOLR index

Tags: json, solr, lucene

I am trying to update SOLR index by Posting RAW JSON data, in version 4.4.0.

Its updating fields fine, but in case of multivalued fields, its not storing multiple values but only the last one.

For e.g-

i. Here is my schema structure-

```
<dynamicField name="amenity_*"  type="text_general"  indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
```

ii. Here is the POST json data-

```
   {"add":{ "doc":{"id":"7986","amenity_GENERAL":{"set":"Overnight Parking"}},"boost":1.0,"overwrite":true,"commitWithin":1000},
   "add":{ "doc":{"id":"7986","amenity_GENERAL":{"set":"Pumps"}},"boost":1.0,"overwrite":true,"commitWithin":1000},
   "add":{ "doc":{"id":"7986","amenity_GENERAL":{"set":"Parking Spaces"}},"boost":1.0,"overwrite":true,"commitWithin":1000}}
```

After a successful post, the Updated index for this id is-

```
     {
        "id": "7986",
        "amenity_GENERAL": [
          "Parking Spaces"
        ],
        "_version_": 1446999052093751300
      },
```

-its storing the last value- "amenity_GENERAL" from the JSON request.

I am not sure, if I need to change the POST JSON structure for that multivalued field or not.

Thanks in advance.

---

**EDIT:** This script will run into a CRON, so each time need to do an Update of index. In case of multivalued field, need to avoid duplicate values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Refer: http://yonik.com/solr/atomic-updates/

`set` – set or replace a particular value, or remove the value if null is specified as the new value

`add` – adds an additional value to a list

i.e. try

```
"amenity_GENERAL":{"add":"Parking Spaces"}
```

Comment: Thanks for ur reply. Yes using 'add', instead of 'set' works, but my script will run in a CRON, after certain interval. I want a full replacement each time.  Doing an 'add', will just continue adding same values into the array. Any suggestion? Thanks in advance

Comment: can't u use `set` with null as the first update to clear the values and then use `add` for the new entries?

Comment: "set" with null adds null string. So, doing a "set" to the first entry & then "add" the others. But just wondering if there is any other 
simpler way. BTW, thnx

Comment: of course, if you know all the values then simply use `"amenity_GENERAL":{"set": ["Overnight Parking", "Pumps", "Parking Spaces"]}`